# create cross table structure with dictionary

Tags: c#

I want to create a datastore class that holds some goods and their amount. An example would be a shopping cart with some articles and their amount.

This `Store` class should behave like a database cross table

```
ID | Amount
-----------
1  | 432
2  | 52345234
3  | 243545
4  | 1123
5  | 235345645
6  | 3434
7  | 33342
8  | 5543
9  | 665675
10 | 3445
```

I thought about using a dictionary that holds the ID and the amount.

```
class Store
{
    public Store()
    {
        goods = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // There might be 10 goods in the database
        {
            goods.Add(i, 0); // initialize with an amount of 0
        }
    }

    Dictionary<int, int> goods; // <ID, Amount>

    public void ChangeGoodAmount(int goodId, int goodAmountModifier) // add or remove goods
    {
        goods.Where(valuePair => valuePair.Key == goodId).First().Value += goodAmountModifier;
    }
}
```

I can't modify the amount because the `Value` is readonly. Is a workaround possible or maybe there is a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
goods.Where(valuePair => valuePair.Key == goodId).First().Value += goodAmountModifier;
```

with

```
if (goods.ContainsKey(goodId))
{
    goods[goodId] += goodAmountModifier;
}
```

You don't have to use LINQ here to find the entry you want to change. I added a check to be sure you don't have an exception when the goodId is not available.

With `goods[goodId]` you can access the value.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't access directly your dictionnary

```
    public void ChangeGoodAmount(int goodId, int goodAmountModifier) // add or remove goods
    {
        if(goods.ContainsKey(goodId))
            goods[goodId] += goodAmountModifier;
    }
```

Comment: will throw an exception if dictionary does not contain that key

Comment: And now you have the same answer like I made some minutes before 
 you :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the dictionary for write access and [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get any existing value. If you access the [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=netframework-4.7.2) to read the existing value but it does not yet exist it will throw a `KeyNotFoundException`. The code below will create a new entry in the dictionary with the value in `goodAmountModifier` if `goodId` is not found in the dictionary, otherwise it will modify the value by adding `goodAmountModifier`.

```
public void ChangeGoodAmount(int goodId, int goodAmountModifier) // add or remove goods
{
    int existingValue = 0;
    goods.TryGetValue(goodId, out existingValue); // attempts to retrieve the existing value
    goods[goodId] = existingValue + goodAmountModifier; // assign a value
}
```